# How do I copy formating in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

When I use VBA to copy most of the things I need follow. Except the width of columns and heigth of rows, how could I do this to include that? Im using this code:

```
Set wk = ThisWorkbook
Dim template As String

template = Sheets("Data").Range("EU12").Value

wk.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:BA1000").Copy wk.Sheets(template).Range("A1")
```

I tried this(without the ' of course, but this give me a 400 error message:

```
'Columns("A:BA").Select
 '   Selection.Copy
  '  Sheets("jan 20").Select
  '  Columns("A:BA").Select
  '  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
  '      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  '  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Did You try to record macro doing this actions?

Comment: You would also benefit from reading this [How to Avoid Using Select](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/how-to-avoid-the-select-method/)

Comment: The second code, the one I tried is from recording a macro. 
I will see if that can help!

Comment: @Nick did you try using an other `XlPasteType` As I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774558/11167163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try stuff like this `xlPasteColumnWidths` :

According to the documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.pastespecial?view=vsto-2017) when `XlPasteType = xlPasteColumnWidths`, Only column width of the copied range is pasted.

```
TheRangeThatYouWantToCopy.Copy
TheRangeWhereYouWantToPaste.Parent.Activate
TheRangeWhereYouWantToPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
TheRangeWhereYouWantToPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Hope this helps, Please don't hesitate to leave me feedbacks so I can Improve this answer

Maybe you can try to recise rows like that :

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Autofit
```

or

```
Rows("1:50").RowHeight = 25
```

Comment: You coudl add how you include the rowheigths, I tried just adding another row but changing the "columnwidth" to "rowheigts" but got an error message! (turned out that I did not need that function anyway)

Comment: @Nick Because `rowheigts` isn't an `XlPasteType`

Comment: @Nick May I ask you to accept this answer event if you don’t use it now ? Thanks

Comment: how would you do it to include rowheigts then? I may need it.

Comment: maybe with `xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`

Comment: @Nick or maybe like in my answer